# Translated Oracle ApEx app returning incorrect month abbreviation

Tags: oracle, translation, oracle-apex

We have an ApEx data entry site that is translated into both Mexican Spanish and Canadian French. One of the critical columns on most data tables is the date associated with the data. As such, there are date picker fields for each time this value is needed.

The translations automatically display the month code based on the current language (a date picked in January on the Spanish site will display 'Ene' for enero). Before the date is recorded to the DB, the application format mask '**DD-MON-RR**' is applied; this understands the current language and records the value on the DB in English.

The issue is that the month of December (diciembre) is showing the abbreviation of '**Dec**' rather than '**Dic**'. As a result, error ORA-01843 (not a valid month) is generated and the data is not saved. However, if the entry is manually changed to **##-Dic-##**, the value is recorded correctly without error.

This makes it appear that the automatically-generated month abbreviation for this language is incorrect. Is this a known error with a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about *globalization*, my Apex applications are in Croatian only. However, as a workaround, perhaps you could switch to another date format mask, such as DD.MM.YYYY; doing so, you wouldn't depend on language differences.

Comment: That's a good solution if nothing else will work. My users appreciate the MON format to more quickly understand a particular data point.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, especially if date format in these countries differ (for example, if one uses MM/DD/YYYY and another DD.MM.YYYY. The first two "groups" (months & days) might cause confusion because - what is 05.12.2017? Is it 5th of December or 12th of May? I *hope* that this is not the case in Mexico and Canada.

Comment: The countries do actually report their dates differently, which was exactly my hesitation. As an experiment, I removed the format mask completely, and the date is displayed in ApEx differently for each language, but are recorded correctly as DD-MON-RR in the DB. If this doesn't negatively affect anything else in the app, this might be the solution.

Comment: As far as I can tell, DATE datatype values are stored in the database in a format which is **not readable** by us, humans. In order to represent something meaningful, we use TO_CHAR with appropriate format mask. Apart from that, for displaying purposes we use NLS settings so DD-MON-RR is, I believe, set that way. You can change it using ALTER SESSION or - at the database level - ALTER SYSTEM SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT.